# Need help getting custom form to theme based on selected criteria

Tags: forms, theming

I have a form I want to theme one of two different ways depending on what the user selected.

Say it's a form to show a report about Cats they can choose a summary or a detail report type.

If they choose detail they should get a table that lists cat name, age, color, breed, location.

If they choose summary they get a table that has each breed listed once with the count of cats at that location

Currently to theme my results I am doing the following:

```
if(isset($form_state['storage']['results'])) {


    $form['results'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => theme('cat_detail_results', array('items' => $form_state['storage']['results'])),
    );

}

return $form;

}
```

I thought I would be able to enter an if statement here and achieve what I wanted but it doesn't work.

```
if(isset($form_state['storage']['results'])) {

    if ($form_state['values']['reporttype']=='detail')
     {
    $form['results'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => theme('cat_detail_results', array('items' => $form_state['storage']['results'])),
    );
   }
   else {
      $form['results'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => theme('cat_summary_results', array('items' => $form_state['storage']['results'])),
   }

  }
}

return $form;

}
```

Does any one have any suggestions for what I want to do or do I just need to create a separate form for these two report types?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: version D7 or d6?

Comment: Using D7 @monymirza